# Error generating the database structure

Tags: symfony

Im making my first project with symfony, and after i create the entities to make the database, when i run `php app/console doctrine:schema:create --dump-sql` i get this error

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
Unknown column type "id" requested. Any Doctrine type that you use has to be registered with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType(). You can get a list of all the known types with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::getTypeMap(). If this error occurs during database introspection then you might have forgot to register all database types for a Doctrine Type. Use AbstractPlatform#registerDoctrineTypeMapping() or have your custom types implement Type#getMapped DatabaseTypes(). If the type name is empty you might have a problem with the cache or forgot some mapping information.
```

All my entities/tables have an id autoincremental key so im totally lost on where to search for info o for this error

PS: When I run `php app/console generate:doctrine:entities TfgBundle` everythings gone right.

Answer (score 0):

You probably set the wrong type for the id field, the good type is "integer" and not "id":

```
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id
```

Comment: I try this, and now it said that
 [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]                                      
  No identifier/primary key specified for Entity "tfg\TfgBundle\Entity\Usuari  
  o". Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key.